# SED - remove before 1 and after 2 lines if match

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have following data

```
https://link1.com 
asndiaiusdias Rye ioajsidsauihduiashd
link1.com/image.jpg
$89.99


https://link2.com 
8iqiwudhuiqhwdqwuidhuiqhwi Rye iqwdihqwuidhuiqwhduihqwi   
https://link2.com/image.jpg
$22.99


https://link3.com 
8iqiwudhuiqhwdqwuidhuiqhwi SOMETHING ELSE  iqwdihqwuidhuiqwhduihqwi   
https://link3.com/image.jpg
$42.99



https://link4.com 
iashduhuasdi rye huiqwheui   
https://link4.com/image.jpg
$232.99
```

> **My goal is to in case-sensitive match "Rye"(also rye or RYe or rYe) and delete 1 line before the match and 3 lines after match**

so result should be:

```
https://link3.com 
8iqiwudhuiqhwdqwuidhuiqhwi SOMETHING ELSE  iqwdihqwuidhuiqwhduihqwi   
https://link3.com/image.jpg
$42.99
```

*You can use sed,grep,awk no need to use only sed, just need to work*

Comment: Can you show your attempt.

Comment: I almost solved it
problem is that first sed command is not match incase-sensitive
> sed "/${exclude}/,+2d" -i /tmp/all
> sed '/${exclude2}/{$!N;/\n.*${exclude2}:/!P;D}' -i /tmp/all

Comment: This is simple with `awk`. Have you tried it?

Comment: I have not tried awk yet. I will show you my commands, just 1 min

Comment: You mean that you want a case insensitive match.  Or "non case-sensitive".  In a case sensitive match, "rye" does not match "Rye"

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `awk` with an empty `RS`:

```
awk -v RS= '$3 !~ /^[rR][yY][eE]$/' file
```

```
https://link3.com
8iqiwudhuiqhwdqwuidhuiqhwi SOMETHING ELSE  iqwdihqwuidhuiqwhduihqwi
https://link3.com/image.jpg
$42.99
```

Comment: I think you'll have false matches since you don't constrain it to second field.  OP didn't ask it either but based on the example that's implied..

Comment: wouldn't you want to include word boundaries to except the (although slim) change of substrings being `rye`?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use Perl for a job like this:

```
$ perl -i -pe 'BEGIN{undef $/;} s/.*?\n.*rye.*?\n(^.*?\n){3}///mig' input.txt
```

Comment: still `\r?` is unnecessary - https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#The-dot `.` matches over it already. Also, you do not need `/m` in this case since ^ is not necessary in this case either. Also "Does it work" isn't always the opposite of "is it wrong"

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -v RS= 'tolower($3) != "rye"' file
https://link3.com
8iqiwudhuiqhwdqwuidhuiqhwi SOMETHING ELSE  iqwdihqwuidhuiqwhduihqwi
https://link3.com/image.jpg
$42.99
```

or if you can have multiple blocks of text output and want them each separated by a blank line:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' 'tolower($3) != "rye"' file
https://link3.com
8iqiwudhuiqhwdqwuidhuiqhwi SOMETHING ELSE  iqwdihqwuidhuiqwhduihqwi
https://link3.com/image.jpg
$42.99
```

Answer (score 0):

every other answer is assuming that 1 line before and 3 after actually means paragraphs:

```
$ perl -00 -ne 'print if !/\Wrye\W/i' input.txt
https://link3.com
8iqiwudhuiqhwdqwuidhuiqhwi SOMETHING ELSE  iqwdihqwuidhuiqwhduihqwi
https://link3.com/image.jpg
$42.99
```

- `-00` enables paragraph mode
- `-n` doesn't print records by default
- `'print if !/\Wrye\W/i` - prints a paragraph unless it matches

however if 1 line before and 3 after needs to be taken literally:

```
$ perl -0777 -pe 's/.*\n.*\Wrye\W.*\n(.*\n){3}//ig' input.txt


https://link3.com
8iqiwudhuiqhwdqwuidhuiqhwi SOMETHING ELSE  iqwdihqwuidhuiqwhduihqwi
https://link3.com/image.jpg
$42.99
```

- `-0777` read the entire file
- `-p` print
- `.*\n` - match a line including the end of line (note that without `/s` `.` doesn't match `\n`)

**Note:** somebody has raised the dos compatibility issue in a comment. The ["."](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#The-dot) matches any character except newline, which includes `\r`, thus `.*\n` covers also dos line endings.

Answer (score -1):

```sh
$ sed -e "/${exclude}/I,+2d" -i /path/to/file
```

then I easily managed deleting before line

Comment: Don't do that. It's fragile (will fail for various values of `exclude` and for various input file contents), incomplete, and you'll notice that no-one who knows sed plus other tools suggested you use sed for this.

Comment: And it doesn't even delete line before matching pattern.